# Mac app: How to test mac app push notifications on production server?

Tags: xcode, macos, push-notification, production, apple-developer

Currently, I have a server that sends notifications to my Mac App. However, before I release the app I would like to be able to send push notifications to my app using the production key instead of the development (sandbox) key and use the production server. This way I can make sure everything will work fine on the App Store. I know iPhone has adhoc that allows this, but mac doesn't seem to have this option. There is a development profile, but it only works in a development (sandbox) environment. Any way to test mac app push notification in production mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are ways to test APN with the Apple Push Notification service SSL (Production) certificate, although your app will then be using the production environment instead, and the entitlement will need to be changed:

`com.apple.developer.aps-environment` from `developer` to `production`.

> Many push notification servers do not handle error responses or
>   dropped connections robustly. An easy way to check this is to
>   intentionally send a notification to a sandbox environment device
>   token, assuming your server is communicating with the production push
>   environment. Doing that should return an invalid token response and
>   drop the connection. To learn more about checking error responses from
>   the push service, please see [Push Notification Throughput and Error Checking](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG44)

Having two environments allows wiggle room for mishaps while you are building your app. If confident with the way in which the server sends and the app receives APN's in the sandbox then create the production certificate and send yourself a notification to ensure it's working.

> <sub>**Note:** There is a separate persistent connection to the push service
>   for each environment. The operating system establishes a persistent
>   connection to the sandbox environment for development builds, while ad
>   hoc and distribution builds connect to the production environment.</sub>

Comment: It seems that I need my app to run on production mode. How do I do that outside the App store. iOS has adhoc, but mac doesn't. I've set com.apple.developer.aps-environment to production, but I still get the sandbox device token because my App isn't running  with my distribution/production  profile.

Comment: @Weakman10122: Generate the Production certificates for your app as you did the sandbox Development certificates,  and replace them with the Production Certificates. They should work outside of the App Store like the sandbox versions, except you need to change the entitlement mentioned above, and you won't be using the Development certificates.

Comment: @Weakman10122 Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem. Just getting a sandbox token even if I change com.apple.developer.aps-environment to production. Xcode does not like that I change this manually.

Comment: @jannej: Did you create Production certificates also?

Comment: Yes, I got it working now. Mostly it was my mistake. However, Xcode automatically changes this flag when making a release build. Which is maybe not the most intuitive thing. I